# How to build a Nuget package with both an assembly and a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, blazor, nuget, webassembly

I am trying to create a NuGet package that includes one assembly and one JavaScript file that I can use in a Blazor app.  I am targeting .Net 6.0 since it is LTS and I will want to publish the final NuGet package for public use if I can get it to work.
My desired outcome is to end up with the *TestClassLibrary.dll* in the target projects lib folder
and the *TestJSUtility.js* file in the *wwwroot/js* folder in the target application. I have consulted the MS docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec?source=recommendations#specifying-files-to-include-in-the-package and I think I have everything right. The command that I run to create the nupkg is as follows:

```
D:\src\Sandbox\TestNugetWithJS\TestClassLibrary>nuget pack TestClassLibrary.1.0.1.nuspec
Attempting to build package from 'TestClassLibrary.1.0.1.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'D:\src\Sandbox\TestNugetWithJS\TestClassLibrary\TestClassLibrary.1.0.1.nupkg'.
```

Below is my *TestClassLibrary.1.0.1.nuspec* file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">

<!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec?source=recommendations#specifying-files-to-include-in-the-package -->
  <metadata>
    <id>TestClassLibrary</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>TestClassLibrary</title>
    <authors>TestClassLibrary</authors>
    <description>Just a test Library</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net6.0">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.JSInterop" version="6.0.24" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
     <files include="any/any/wwwroot/js/TestJSUtility.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="D:\src\Sandbox\TestNugetWithJS\TestClassLibrary\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestClassLibrary.dll" target="lib\net6.0\TestClassLibrary.dll" />
    <file src="D:\src\Sandbox\TestNugetWithJS\TestClassLibrary\wwwroot\js\TestJSUtility.js" target="wwwroot\js\TestJSUtility.js" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Following is the layout of my project that has the source for the package:

[image: Project Layout]

Following is a screen shot of the *TestClassLibrary.1.0.1.nupkg* after I changed it to a *.zip* showing that the files I wanted to include are indeed present

[image: Screen Shot of JavaScript file within the nupkg file]

Following is a screen shot of the *test project* after I installed the NuGet package.

[image]

The problem is that when I include this NuGet package in a project, the java script file does not get included. My *TestClassLibrary.dll* just has dynamic loading of the *js* file and if I manually copy it over to the project, everything works.
The code that my NuGet package runs to load the *js* file is as follows:

```cs
public async Task<int> AddTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
{
  await using (IJSObjectReference jsUtility = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/TestJSUtility.js"))
  {
     int result = await jsUtility.InvokeAsync<int>("simpleAdder", a, b);
     return result;
  }
}
```

This is actually a silly project to show the issue I am having which is in a much bigger more complex project, but if I can get this to work, the *nuspec* file should port over.

My question is: How do I build a NuGet package that actually installs not only the *dll*, but also the *js* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `_content` path for RCL's:

```
"./_content/[YOUR RCL NAME SPACE]/js/TestJSUtility.js"
```

[image]

##### Example1.razor

```
"./_content/SomeRazorClassLibrary/scripts/some-script.js"
```

##### Example2.razor

```
"./_content/SomeRazorClassLibrary/Views/Example2.razor.js"
```

Comment: Thank you - the problem was that I built my Nuget component as a regular .Net Class Library rather than a RazorClassLibrary.  After changing it to a RazorClassLibrary, and changing my "dynamic load" to the *_content* path it worked.